# Mysql Error when creating trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
error note:Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@sum int default 0;
    set @sum=(select count(*) from inserted);
    if @sum>1 then
    ' at line 5
```

and this is the code:

```
delimiter //

create trigger insert_only_one

after insert on sc

for each row

begin

declare @sum int default 0;

set @sum=(select count(*) from inserted);

if @sum>1 then

print('dont insert more than one record');

rollback transaction

end
```

The error note shows I have error at line 5.
I tried `int(5)` or just 'int', with or without `default 0` still can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare variable because you are using @sum variable that is initialized automatically..

you can't print anything inside a trigger...

Also your command rollback transaction is Invalid for MySQL.
Use only rollback with semicolon..

Comment: yep, thx, btw, all variables don't need to declare in mysql? just use them?